# In Ruby on Rails Restful Authentication, UsersController#new, a @user = User.new is used. Is it actually needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

After

```
script/generate authenticated user sessions
```

`users_controller.rb` is created with

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

and the view has this line:

```
@user.password = @user.password_confirmation = nil
```

and that's it.  Is this actually needed?  I mean the form will POST to `/users` which is by RESTful routing, going to `UsersController#create`, so the `@user` created actually is never used.  Is it actually needed and why?  thanks.

---

**Update:**  `@user` is never used again any where else... also, I tried removing those two lines

```
@user = User.new
```

and

```
@user.password = @user.password_confirmation = nil
```

and I can still use the form to create a new user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view it kind of makes sense. Let say user account creation fails - you'll be re-rendering the `new` view with a different (not new) `@user` object. I'd probably reset the password and password_confirmation in the action.

Comment: hm... you mean, let's say if the login name or email was already registered, and it won't pass the validation, and it won't go to the controller again but re-render the view... and we don't want to render the view with the password already filled in the form... so that's why we use the line `@user.password = @user.password_confirmation = nil` to blank the password out -- purely for failed validation purpose...  actually, `<% form_for :user, :url => users_path do |f| -%>` will pre-fill the form using the other values... so `:user` is as good as `@user`...

Comment: looks like if `@user` isn't created, `form_for` will create it... and if already created, then won't bother to create it... in order to clear the password fields, it has to be created in the controller... unless in the view we say `@user.password = @user.password_confirmation = nil if (defined? @user) && !@user.nil?`

Comment: You pretty much have it - what I was saying is that I'd blank out the passwords in the controller instead of the view, if needed. From what you've looked at, it seems that @user isn't needed for a "fresh" `new` request, however @user will be used on a failed user creation. To try this out, rename @user to something else in the controller and see how your view behaves on a failed user account creation.

Comment: if I remove it in controller, then the view will say `undefined method password_confirmation= for nil:NilClass` when the sign up form is supposed to be displayed... but if I already have invalid fields and then rename to `@user2` in controller, the view actually renders ok... If I remove that line in view that sets password to nil, then it has the undesirable effect of not blanking out the password and is in the form, viewable in the HTML source... but... actually the form is submitted in HTTP, so those password are viewable for any network interceptor anyways... pre-filling it should be ok?

Answer (score 1):

It is needed to render proper form on view. Forms can say if it is just non-saved objects, like here, so form will create post request. If it is a user that was found in DB, then it will automatically create PUT request for update.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%#= something %>  
<% end %>
```

It will behave differently if you do in your controller User.new, or User.find(id)

Comment: It is using `<% form_for :user, :url => users_path do |f| -%>`... the `@user` was never used again any where else...   please also see update #1 in the question