# Reason for adding an @user variable to the new action(def new @user = User.new end)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am  trying to build user signup form by following 
  Michael Hart's  Rubyonrails book. 
[Chapter 7:Singup](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up)

However I simply couldn't wrap my head around this little piece of code.

```
def new 
    @user = User.new
  end
```

I want to know what is the purpose of the above code and how it works?

If I exclude above code (@user=User.new) deliberately, it'll throw error message saying:

```
raised: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

If first argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty,why declaring @user=User.new get passed since it assign nil value to user object.My naive understanding of rails can be wrong here.

Here is the full code

*controller/user_controller.rb*

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end  

  def new 
    @user = User.new
  end

   def create
     @user = User.new(user_params)   # Not the final implementation!
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user

    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

*views/users/new.html.erb*

> <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
>           <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
>
> ```
>   <%= f.label :name %>
>   <%= f.text_field :name %>
>
>   <%= f.label :email %>
>   <%= f.text_field :email %>
>
>   <%= f.label :password %>
>   <%= f.password_field :password %>
>
>   <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
>   <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
>
>   <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
> <% end %>   </div> </div>
> ```

Before presenting this questions to respectable stackoverflow community I looked for the answer at the following links:-

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

[First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty Hartl's Rails 4 Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804050/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-hartls-rails-4-tutorial)

[In Ruby on Rails Restful Authentication, UsersController#new, a @user = User.new is used. Is it actually needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147063/in-ruby-on-rails-restful-authentication-userscontrollernew-a-user-user-new)

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens in the line

```
def new 
  @user = User.new
end
```

is, rails is creating an instance variable called `@user` (ruby uses `@` sign for instance variables) and assigns a new `User` model. This could be most of the time the `User` model in

`app/models/user.rb`

and then it passes to your view `#app/vies/users/new.html.erb`.

and remember, initializing a new `User` object and assign in to `@user` is not same as assign `nil` value to the `@user`

Then comes your second question, Why its giving an error when you exclude it deliberately.

So the reason behind that is,

when u say `@user = User.new` and pass the `@user` variable to rails form_helper. (`<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`), so `form_helper` automatically dose some things for you,

If you get the html source for the page it will be like

`<form action="/users" id="new_user" method="post">
</form>`

it means rails form helper is creating the `routes`, post method (`post`) etc for you. from your line `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`. As u may already understand now, if you just pass 'nil`via`@user = nil`, rails`form_helper`  cannot do all that processing stuff , thats why you are getting the above error.

read more about [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)  , HTH

Comment: For deeper understanding reading [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) recommended by sameera207 is a must.

Answer (score 0):

When you type

> @user = User.new

You create Model's object user with empty fields. This variable is instance variable for this object and you can access to it in your view and you use it in form fields

```
form_for(@user)
```

Fields in your form in view is specify fields of this variable, but variable cannot be nil. If you haven't variable @user, you may use any another variable and set it by symbol.
Well variable for **form_for** must be instance variable( start with @ ) or specified in .erb file

When you submitting form, you send hash where variable has hash with fields for example
**params**
`{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx=", "user"=>{"email"=>"qwerty@qwerty.qw", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create user"}`